# What is the default PATH environment variable setting on fresh install of Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, path

A user of ours cleared their path, thanks to some directions on the internet.

What is the default path, I am a developer so I have tons of extra stuff in mine, what should my user get on a plain jane one?

Comment: this one http://superuser.com/questions/193368/what-are-default-system-path-settings-on-windows-7-64bit (at risk of being closed as a duplicate)  says %CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\   i.e. it mentions a WindowsLive  directory

Comment: Related: If it's not too late to try to restore it from a backup, you can https://superuser.com/questions/523688/how-to-restore-the-path-environment-variable-i-deleted

Comment: Missing the question for `default path` on `Windows 10`. Maybe [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45072617/default-values-of-path-variables-in-windows-10)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

According to [this MVP](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vistaappearance/thread/d93488bf-e528-4268-93eb-07bf6274d509), on Vista it was:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem
```

I would assume the same for Windows 7.  I also have `\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\` as one of my first entries so you might want to add it as well since PowerShell was shipped with Windows 7.

Comment: PowerShell path is included in default system path in W7

Comment: this one you were keen to close  http://superuser.com/questions/193368/what-are-default-system-path-settings-on-windows-7-64bit   has a slightly different one to the one you state, e.g. it has a WindowsLive directory, though you didn't give any critique of it

Answer (score 32):

I just finished installing Windows 7 Enterprise SP1-U (x64 English) in a virtual machine. I can certify the following as the default `Path` environment variables. Note that I haven't installed anything (not even the "additions", "drivers", or "tools") into the virtual machine.

Default system `Path` environment variable (the inconsistent capitalization is as-is):

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

There is no default user `Path` environment variable (i.e., no such variable was set).

Answer (score 2):

Sorry, mine's no longer "plain jane" but I've removed the obvious added items (this is on 64 bit, remove the (x86) bits if you're on 32):

```
PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

Answer (score 1):

There's really no such thing as a default Path; it changes as software and devices are installed/removed. However, at a bare minimum, your Path should contain:

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```