# What are default system path settings on Windows 7 64bit?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, path

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the default PATH environment variable setting on fresh install of Windows 7](https://superuser.com/questions/124239/what-is-the-default-path-environment-variable-setting-on-fresh-install-of-windows)

It seems that my PATH settings were deleted by some program (it currently has only entries for Digital Mars D utilities), so I'm asking what directories are included in path by default? Even the most basic things such as tracert or ping are not working for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have:

`%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\`

Comment: A fresh Windows installation does not have `%CommonProgramFiles%\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live`.

Answer (score 2):

See the Windows 7 column in [Default Values on Microsoft Windows](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_Values_on_Microsoft_Windows).

Comment: I don't think this actually answers the question. It might show the default values for the variable names, but it doesn't show what the default PATH settings are.

Comment: In the table, `%PATH%` and `%PSModulePath%` rows specify the default PATH settings.

Comment: they don't specify whether powershell is there or not in the PATH, and if anything it suggests it's not there by default, when quite likely it is.