# Standard value of PATH variable Windows 10

Tags: windows, environment-variables, path

After having poorly handled the PATH system variable (resulting in deletion), I'm now looking to reinstate the variable with the original value.
I found answers like [this one](https://superuser.com/questions/676695/i-overwrote-my-environment-variable-path) about Windows 8 and below, but not for Windows 10.

I guess values are virtually identical, but I'd like to know the exact string so I'm not missing anything.

EDIT: Also, Regedit tree have changed and I'm not able to locate the variable

Comment: The default PATH variable is identical to what it was for Windows 8.1, Windows 8.0, and Windows 7.

Comment: AT Ramhound are you sure that is true?  The answer here for win10  lists powershell(which I presume is correct and you don't differ with it either),  You claim windows 7 is the same, yet This link for win7 doesn't list powershell http://www.binbert.com/blog/2010/09/default-environment-variable-values-of-windows-7-xp/ and neither does this link here http://superuser.com/questions/124239/what-is-the-default-path-environment-variable-setting-on-fresh-install-of-window  (cont)

Comment: Can you state the source or sources for your claim?  You may be right   as http://superuser.com/questions/193368/what-are-default-system-path-settings-on-windows-7-64bit lists powershell    However, I see windowsLive on a windows 7 system. and syberdoor's answer doesn't list it

Comment: furthermore this link  http://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/3234-environment-variables-windows-10-a.html  doesn't mention windowslive as a default  for windows 10   This link re win7 mentions windowslive http://superuser.com/questions/193368/what-are-default-system-path-settings-on-windows-7-64bit  whereas this one doesn't http://superuser.com/questions/124239/what-is-the-default-path-environment-variable-setting-on-fresh-install-of-window

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This is copied from a Win 10 Enterprise 64Bit System I set up yesterday (no programs installed yet):

```
%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```

seems to be identical with the Windows 8 one you found.

28.11.2003: As this is still a frequently visited question I wanted to update it with the status for 22H2 for Windows 10 and 23H2 for Windows 11 (both Enterprise). It seems current builds have an additional Entry

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\OpenSSH
```

added at the end