# Commands ping and ipconfig are not recognized

Tags: command-line, windows-10, ipconfig

Why are the commands `ipconfig` and `ping` not recognized in the command prompt on my windows 10 PC? How do I recognize this commands? Here you've a screenshot.

[image]<sup>(Click on image to watch in full screen)</sup>

Comment: have you don't anything with your environment variable/path lately? type "path" in cmd and show us that too pls

Comment: Your path is broken.

Comment: Relevant: [What are PATH and other environment variables, and how can I set or use them?](http://superuser.com/q/284342)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Go to Properties in My computer → Advanced system settings → Advanced → Environment Variables.
2. Select 'PATH' from the list of system variables and edit and set PATH to `c:\windows\system32;`.

This will solve your problem.

<sup>This answer was taken from [howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/forum/topic/ping-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command).</sup>

Comment: This is a bad answer. The rest of the default path is missing. It should be `PATH=C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\ `. See [Standard value of PATH variable Windows 10](http://superuser.com/q/973153)

Comment: +1 on the answer, though I do agree with @DavidPostill. :) A tip, you might want to learn a bit about `formatting` to make your answer more readable. :)

Comment: I think this answer is wrong. 

a) There is not "set path to" option in dhe Environment Variables dialog window. There's an **edit** button. You can edit specific members of the Path variable.

b) There are two types of Environment Variables in this dialog: **user** and **system**. You should edit the Path **system** variable.

c) If missing, **add**  `%SystemRoot%\system32` to the Path **system** variable.