# Messed up OS settings - Administrative settings

Tags: windows-10, operating-systems, regedit

I did mess up with my Administrative System Settings on my Windows 10.
Now I cannot open the System Protection settings for restoring to the earlier point or cannot open anything.

I tried to set the environment variable for Python 3.6. That is where my things went wrong. Cannot use the system recovery to the previous point.

Apologize I should have done that, part of my learning phase.

I am getting error

[image]

Comment: [First step is to restore the original value path variable](https://superuser.com/questions/124239/what-is-the-default-path-environment-variable-setting-on-fresh-install-of-window).  You can also just remove what you added to the variable to achieve the same results.

Comment: @ManojSawai, it is Windir . Originally there is C:\WINDOWS and to that I have added the python home path

Comment: @DBOn - The default variable has more than just `C:\Windows` by default.  The obvious solution is just to add the path to the require executable to the variable.  This will allow you to use a restoration point.

Comment: Sorry @Ramhound , when I checked I can see only C:\Windows , not able to open again to cross check and confirm you back , apologize

Comment: Tried adding the path above in error block like C:\Python36_home\System32\    but couldnot get through

Comment: What do you mean "you couldn't get through".  You will have to restart/logout of your current user before it will work once you restore the default value/missing value

Comment: ok will restart and confirm back now

Comment: use this tool to change the path varaible: https://www.rapidee.com/en/path-variable